# "session_start()" generates new session id instead of loading the available one

Tags: php, browser, wamp, session-cookies

A new session id is created in the session folder with every session_start() call, but never loaded on the next page.

The code I used to check it:

(there is no code and there are no whitespaces before "session_start();", this is directly at the top)

```
<?php
session_start();

var_dump($_SESSION);
echo boolStr(is_writable(session_save_path())) . " and ";
echo boolStr(is_readable(session_save_path())) . "<br>";

if (!isset($_SESSION['counter'])){
    $_SESSION['counter']=0;
}

echo "Refreshed: ". $_SESSION['counter'] ." times.<br>
$_SESSION['counter']++;

<a href=".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?'.session_name().'='.session_id().">refresh!</a>"; 


function boolStr($val)
    {
        return $val ? 'true' : 'false';
    }
?>
```

The counter variable increases with "$_SESSION['counter']++;" but is again at 0 after loading the refreshed page, and the session id changes in the address bar.

The output:

```
D:\wamp64\www\sessions.php:4:
array (size=0) 
  empty

true and true
Refreshed 0 times.
refresh
```

php.ini:

```
session.save_handler = files
session.save_path ="D:/wamp64/tmp"
session.use_strict_mode = 0
session.use_cookies = 1
session.use_only_cookies = 1
session.name = PHPSESSID
session.auto_start = 0
session.cookie_lifetime = 0
session.cookie_path = /
session.cookie_domain = /
session.cookie_httponly = 1
session.cookie_secure = 0
session.serialize_handler = php
session.gc_probability = 1
session.gc_divisor = 1000
session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440
session.referer_check =
session.entropy_length = 32
session.entropy_file = /dev/urandom
session.cache_limiter = nocache
session.cache_expire = 180
session.use_trans_sid = 0
session.hash_function = sha256
session.hash_bits_per_character = 5
```

Sessions were working fine for the last month, but when I closed the browser (I hibernate the pc and almost never shutdown), the problem appeared. I don't really see a connection with the browser though because I tried it with Chrome afterwards instead of Firefox and it had the same problem.

How do I know what happens when session_start() tries loading a session cookie? If I was able to look at how session_start() works maybe I could find out what's happening.

Thanks.

Comment: When doing `error_reporting(E_ALL);` what do you return?

Comment: I don't know if I did it wrong so I placed it once below session_start() and once above it, and didn't get any error both times.

Comment: Try to move $_SESSION['counter']++ above the echo statement into a variable. For example: $session_counter = $_SESSION['counter']++;

Comment: The counter gets increased, I checked on that. The problem is in retrieving it from the saved session file.

Answer (score 0):

After more than a day of trying to figure it out with no results, I thought I might as well install and use XAMPP instead and sessions worked there, so the problem must be coming out of WAMP Server.